# Foundation Global Styles Repeating Unexpectedly in Grunt File

Tags: sass, gruntjs, zurb-foundation, yeoman, grunt-contrib-sass

This is a tricky issue to explain, I'll try and be as thorough as I can:

### My Setup - Using the Jekyllrb Generator

I've taken the [Jekyllrb Yeoman generator](https://github.com/robwierzbowski/generator-jekyllrb) and integrated Zurb's Foundation 5 into it in the most basic way (only using the Sass files) as per Zurb's instructions.

My Sass paths in the **grunt.js** are as follows:

```
loadPath: 'app/_bower_components/foundation/scss'
```

and in my /_scss I have:

```
app.scss
_settings.scss
```

In app.scss - I'm including a number of Foundation components (eg. accordion, type, tabs, etc). Each one brings with it a set of global styles. These styles are wrapped in the following:

```
@include exports("global") { ... }
```

Which according to [this link](https://github.com/wilsonpage/sass-import-once):

> *"When included in a SASS module, sass-import-once will prevent the styles being duplicated if @import is called somewhere else. This is cool because it allows every SASS file to declare its own dependencies. This promotes encapulation and allows modules to standalone if need be."*

#### My Grunt.js

```
// Generated on 2014-09-28 using generator-jekyllrb 1.2.1
'use strict';

// Directory reference:
//   css: css
//   sass: _scss
//   javascript: scripts
//   images: img
//   fonts: fonts

module.exports = function (grunt) {
  // Show elapsed time after tasks run
  require('time-grunt')(grunt);
  // Load all Grunt tasks
  require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

  grunt.initConfig({
    // Configurable paths
    yeoman: {
      app: 'app',
      dist: 'dist'
    },
    watch: {
      sass: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/_scss/**/*.{scss,sass}'],
        tasks: ['sass:server']
      },
      autoprefixer: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/css/**/*.css'],
        tasks: ['copy:stageCss', 'autoprefixer:server']
      },
      jekyll: {
        files: [
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/**/*.{html,yml,md,mkd,markdown}',
          '!<%= yeoman.app %>/_bower_components/**/*'
        ],
        tasks: ['jekyll:server']
      },
      livereload: {
        options: {
          livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
        },
        files: [
          '.jekyll/**/*.html',
          '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.app %>}/css/**/*.css',
          '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.app %>}/<%= js %>/**/*.js',
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/img/**/*.{gif,jpg,jpeg,png,svg,webp}'
        ]
      }
    },
    connect: {
      options: {
        port: 9000,
        livereload: 35729,
        // change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside
        hostname: 'localhost'
      },
      livereload: {
        options: {
          open: true,
          base: [
            '.tmp',
            '.jekyll',
            '<%= yeoman.app %>'
          ]
        }
      },
      dist: {
        options: {
          open: true,
          base: [
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
          ]
        }
      },
      test: {
        options: {
          base: [
            '.tmp',
            '.jekyll',
            'test',
            '<%= yeoman.app %>'
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    clean: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          dot: true,
          src: [
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/*',
            // Running Jekyll also cleans the target directory.  Exclude any
            // non-standard `keep_files` here (e.g., the generated files
            // directory from Jekyll Picture Tag).
            '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git*'
          ]
        }]
      },
      server: [
        '.tmp',
        '.jekyll'
      ]
    },
    sass: {
      options: {
        bundleExec: true,
        debugInfo: false,
        lineNumbers: false,
        loadPath: 'app/_bower_components/foundation/scss'
      },
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/_scss',
          src: '**/*.{scss,sass}',
          dest: '.tmp/css',
          ext: '.css'
        }]
      },
      server: {
        options: {
          debugInfo: false,
          lineNumbers: false
        },
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/_scss',
          src: '**/*.{scss,sass}',
          dest: '.tmp/css',
          ext: '.css'
        }]
      }
    },
    jekyll: {
      options: {
        bundleExec: true,
        config: '_config.yml,_config.build.yml',
        src: '<%= yeoman.app %>'
      },
      dist: {
        options: {
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
        }
      },
      server: {
        options: {
          config: '_config.yml',
          dest: '.jekyll'
        }
      },
      check: {
        options: {
          doctor: true
        }
      }
    },
    useminPrepare: {
      options: {
        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
      },
      html: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/index.html'
    },
    usemin: {
      options: {
        assetsDirs: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
      },
      html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/**/*.html'],
      css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/css/**/*.css']
    },
    htmlmin: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          collapseWhitespace: true,
          collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
          removeAttributeQuotes: true,
          removeRedundantAttributes: true
        },
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          src: '**/*.html',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }]
      }
    },
    // Usemin adds files to concat
    concat: {},
    // Usemin adds files to uglify
    uglify: {},
    // Usemin adds files to cssmin
    cssmin: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          check: 'gzip'
        }
      }
    },
    imagemin: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          progressive: true
        },
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          src: '**/*.{jpg,jpeg,png}',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }]
      }
    },
    svgmin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          src: '**/*.svg',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }]
      }
    },
    copy: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          dot: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
          src: [
            // Jekyll processes and moves HTML and text files.
            // Usemin moves CSS and javascript inside of Usemin blocks.
            // Copy moves asset files and directories.
            'img/**/*',
            'fonts/**/*',
            // Like Jekyll, exclude files & folders prefixed with an underscore.
            '!**/_*{,/**}'
            // Explicitly add any files your site needs for distribution here.
            //'_bower_components/jquery/jquery.js',
            //'favicon.ico',
            //'apple-touch*.png'
          ],
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }]
      }
    },
    filerev: {
      options: {
        length: 4
      },
      dist: {
        files: [{
          src: [
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/**/*.js',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/css/**/*.css',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/img/**/*.{gif,jpg,jpeg,png,svg,webp}',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/fonts/**/*.{eot*,otf,svg,ttf,woff}'
          ]
        }]
      }
    },
    buildcontrol: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          remote: '../',
          branch: 'gh-pages',
          commit: true,
          push: true
        }
      }
    },
    jshint: {
      options: {
        jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
        reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
      },
      all: [
        'Gruntfile.js',
        '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/**/*.js',
        'test/spec/**/*.js'
      ]
    },
    csslint: {
      options: {
        csslintrc: '.csslintrc'
      },
      check: {
        src: [
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/css/**/*.css',
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/_scss/**/*.scss'
        ]
      }
    },
    concurrent: {
      server: [
        'sass:server',
        'jekyll:server'
      ],
      dist: [
        'sass:dist',
        'copy:dist'
      ]
    }
  });

  // Define Tasks
  grunt.registerTask('serve', function (target) {
    if (target === 'dist') {
      return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
    }

    grunt.task.run([
      'clean:server',
      'concurrent:server',
      'connect:livereload',
      'watch'
    ]);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('server', function () {
    grunt.log.warn('The `server` task has been deprecated. Use `grunt serve` to start a server.');
    grunt.task.run(['serve']);
  });

  // No real tests yet. Add your own.
  grunt.registerTask('test', [
  //   'clean:server',
  //   'concurrent:test',
  //   'connect:test'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('check', [
    'clean:server',
    'jekyll:check',
    'sass:server',
    'jshint:all',
    'csslint:check'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean',
    // Jekyll cleans files from the target directory, so must run first
    'jekyll:dist',
    'concurrent:dist',
    'useminPrepare',
    'concat',
    'cssmin',
    'uglify',
    'imagemin',
    'svgmin',
    'filerev',
    'usemin',
    'htmlmin'
    ]);

  grunt.registerTask('deploy', [
    'check',
    'test',
    'build',
    'buildcontrol'
    ]);

  grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'check',
    'test',
    'build'
  ]);
};
```

### The Problem

These global styles are being duplicated in the final compiled stylesheet regardless of the '@include exports' function telling it to resolve duplicates. I've used grunt-contrib-sass before and never run into this problem. Leading me to think some other task may be causing it?

#### On more thing:

I'm aware there is a variable in Foundation's _settings.scss which has:

```
$include-html-global-classes: $include-html-classes;
```

I **do not** want to turn this off - as I ***do*** want the global styles in my stylesheet - I just only want them to appear once.

### I've Setup a Repo

I would be **so very grateful** if anyone could take a look at this for me. I've put together a most basic example to illustrate this problem. A quick look at the inspector (when serving the page) will show you a clutter of duplicated styles in the DOM.

https://github.com/liquidvisual/jekyllrb-foundation-test

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/5877) on the Foundation GitHub, there's a bit of a kerfuffle with Foundation moving fast and breaking things around `exports` behaviour.

I tried your test repository with Foundation rolled back to version `5.4.4` (instead of the latest, which is `5.4.5`) and that worked for me.

So, you just need to change the Foundation dependency in your `bower.json` to:

```
"dependencies": {
    "foundation": "zurb/bower-foundation#5.4.4"
},
```

and things should work.

From what I read on that issue thread, once Foundation releases `5.5` you should be able to switch over to that without any problems.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! It's working great now. I had no idea the extent of troubles Sass and Foundation were going through. I would never have figured this out if not for your response, so thanks again!